# Problem with Python module INSTABOT login

Tags: python, module, timeout

[image: Instabot login error]

I tried the code for last two days, i got the message from my VS code editor, can please anyone help me to solve the problem.

**Code**

```
from instabot import Bot
bot = Bot()
bot.login(username="the_username_hidden" , password="password_hidden")
print("done")
```

**Message Get**

```
2021-04-26 06:38:18,970 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
2021-04-26 06:38:18,971 - INFO - Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!
2021-04-26 06:38:19,434 - ERROR - Request returns 429 error!
2021-04-26 06:38:19,434 - WARNING - That means 'too many requests'. I'll go to sleep for 5 minutes.
2021-04-26 06:43:20,237 - ERROR - Request returns 429 error!
2021-04-26 06:43:20,237 - WARNING - That means 'too many requests'. I'll go to sleep for 10 minutes.
2021-04-26 06:53:21,001 - ERROR - Request returns 429 error!
2021-04-26 06:53:21,001 - WARNING - That means 'too many requests'. I'll go to sleep for 15 minutes.
```

Comment: It's more likely to be the client side problem, same thing was happening to me but after some time it starts working

Answer (score 2):

#With the sleep this will not work. This error occurs because you make too many requests.
bot = Bot()

```
bot.login(...)
```

Try this and let me know if it works.
Could be a fluke.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has banned all bots and APIs. You need to register at the Facebook developer website. https://developers.facebook.com/

Instagram API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview/#authorization-window